# What is `.__DEVTOOLS__.` environment in R package namespace?

Tags: r, r-package

While reading source code of R packages that supple helpers to work with package namespaces, I have noticed that they sometimes refer to a `.__DEVTOOLS__.` environment. But I have never encountered this environment in any package namespace in the wild, nor can I successfully find any information about.

I do understand what other environments are. My first guess would have been that this is related to the {devtools} package, but even that package doesn't have this environment in its namespace.

```r
get_env_from_ns <- function(x) {
  ns <- .getNamespace(x)
  
  c(
    rlang::env_has(ns, ".__NAMESPACE__."),
    rlang::env_has(ns, ".__S3MethodsTable__."),
    rlang::env_has(ns, ".__DEVTOOLS__.")
  )
}

library(devtools)
#> Loading required package: usethis
get_env_from_ns("devtools")
#>      .__NAMESPACE__. .__S3MethodsTable__.       .__DEVTOOLS__. 
#>                 TRUE                 TRUE                FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

So I had two questions:

- What is this environment?
- Is there an example of a package that uses this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.__DEVTOOLS__.` was the name of an environment created by the `devtools` package. If you search for that in the `[devtools package NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/news/news.html) you'll find that it says

> Packages loaded with load_all now store devtools metadata in their namespace environment, in a variable called `.__DEVTOOLS__.` This can be accessed with the dev_meta function. (Winston Chang. Fixes #128)

It appeared in a the [metatdata.R file](https://github.com/wch/devtools/blob/e2b105d8abd2373af184401507ff2537fae6080d/R/metadata.r). It appears that this environment is no longer used by the package to track metadata so the function seems to be written to work with an older version of the package.